# how to show two div only at onetime?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me how to show two div one at time ?
Actually I make one demo where I scroll to top it create one div and prepend to main div.But I want only two div show at one time.Now it will create new divs whenever user goes to top.I want user remove below div.

```
Example on starting : it show On div id="page_5"
when user scroll up it create  div id="page_4" .It is fine
But when user scroll again it create  div id="page_3" but that time I need user delete that div id="page_5" from below.again user go up it remove div id="page_4".


if user come down it remove upper div and show below div .remove remove div id="page_1" or remove div id="page_2" and show div id="page_5" or div id="page_4"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gbd3z/2/

```
var pages = [page_1, page_2, page_3, page_4,page_5];
 var totalPage = "page_" + pages.length;
$("<div id='" + totalPage + "'>" + pages.pop() + "</div>").prependTo($("#fullContainer"));


    $("#fullContainer").scroll(function () {
        // top
        if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0 && pages.length) {
            console.log("up");
            var stringLoad = "page_" + pages.length;
            $("<div id='" + stringLoad + "'>" + pages.pop() + "</div>").prependTo($("#fullContainer"));
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight) {
            console.log("down");
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can just use classes: http://jsfiddle.net/Gbd3z/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#fullContainer").scroll(function () {
    // top
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0 && pages.length) {
        console.log("up");
        var stringLoad = "page_" + pages.length;
        $("<div id='" + stringLoad + "'>" + pages.pop() + "</div>").prependTo($("#fullContainer"));

        //remove element at 2nd index
        $('#fullContainer').children().slice(2).remove()
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight) {
        console.log("down");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N5LZB/)

Comment: can you please prove fiddle ..and what about when user scroll down

Comment: that is correct answer what will happen when user scroll down